# setInterval for translate3d, requestAnimationFrame or CSS3 animation repaint issue in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, setinterval, requestanimationframe

I made a small plugin that infinitely loops the background. Before coding I tested several ways of doing this and anything with background-position was messing with repaints. 
http://jsfiddle.net/3tQsc/718/

So I made translate3d version thinking that CPU acceleration would save me. Now script is done but Firefox has repaint issue on scroll.

http://jsfiddle.net/e9frkff1/2/
full screen
https://jsfiddle.net/e9frkff1/2/embedded/result/

all other browsers perform normally.

If you set the setInterval to anything below 60 it is messing with FF

Than I tough that [rAF](http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/) would save me,

```
        setInterval(function(){
            requestAnimationFrame(bgscroll);
        },options.durration);
```

but now in FF I see the chop 
http://jsfiddle.net/e9frkff1/3/

full screen
https://jsfiddle.net/e9frkff1/3/embedded/result/

Than I tough ok , maybe I am doing to much here , lets just do CSS3 animation

and FF again chop , even worse than all other versions 
http://jsfiddle.net/e9frkff1/4/

here is a video of what I see in FF
First 8 SEC is  CSS3 animation chop
the rest 18 is scroll chop
http://www.screencast.com/t/hTHQFR44
just so that you dont think I am going crazy here.

In the video , during the scroll at some point it lets go and continues the smoothscroll. Have no idea why.

My machine  http://prntscr.com/8hpfxh

my gc GTX 970

Firefox  version 40.0.3

also tested this on other machines and see same issue.

Can someone enlighten me here and possibly provide a solution to this.

Comment: You use [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) in wrong way. It shouldn't be used with `setInterval`. I recommend you to read [this article](http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/)

Comment: @hindmost  I dont know how to set timer the other way , If you do please provide a sample.

Comment: The point is that with `requestAnimationFrame` you don't need a timer at all, since this function replace timer functionality. See the article above for a sample.

Comment: @hindmost  , look http://jsfiddle.net/e9frkff1/5/   how do I go faster/slower now ?